# How to implement SWIPE VIEW for phonegap-android dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, iscroll, swipeview

I am aiming to do a phone gap-android project.

I want to implement the swipe view **(as in android with page-controller)** in phone gap but preferably using Java script.

I saw there are  many options such as

[hammer](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/),[zepto](http://zeptojs.com/#Touch%20events),[jquerysloution](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html),[quo](http://quojs.tapquo.com/) & [iScroll](https://github.com/ccoenraets/mobile-ui-patterns/tree/master/page-swipe-iscroll).

**Which is the best one out of these or anything else that better to implement?(preferably in java script )**

I also notice that for all these we need to give the no of contents for the swipes such as page 1, page 2....etc.

**How to create a swipe view based on the no of contents in the database?

i have tried implementing using iscroll...

this the scroll.js code..

```
document.addEventListener("orientationchange", updateLayout);

// The wrapperWidth before orientationChange. Used to identify the current page number in updateLayout();
wrapperWidth = 0;

var myScroll = new iScroll("pageWrapper", {
    snap: true,
    momentum: false,
    hScrollbar: false,
    vScrollbar: false,
        lockDirection: true});

    updateLayout();

    function updateLayout() {

        var currentPage = 0;

        if (wrapperWidth > 0) {
            currentPage = - Math.ceil( $("#swipe_body").position().left / wrapperWidth);
        }

        wrapperWidth = $("#pageWrapper").width();

        $("#swipe_body").css("width", wrapperWidth * 4);
        $(".page").css("width", wrapperWidth - 40);
        myScroll.refresh();
        myScroll.scrollToPage(currentPage, 0, 0);
    }

    page3Scroll = new iScroll("wrapper", {hScrollbar: false, vScrollbar: false, lockDirection: true });
```

and i copied the **iscroll.js** from [here](https://github.com/ccoenraets/mobile-ui-patterns/blob/master/page-swipe-iscroll/iscroll.js)

when i run the program i get an error as

```
04-22 18:26:01.892: E/Web Console(2453): TypeError: Result of expression 'that.wrapper' [null] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/www/iscroll.js:57
```

**As,i was facing errors, i tried implementing it with SwipeView.js from [here] (https://github.com/cubiq/SwipeView/blob/master/src/swipeview.js) it goes in to the loop..the page controller is displayed but.the following things are missing**

- the page controller is been seen vertically and not horizontally
- the images set for the swipe view are not visible.
- the page moves vertically and not horizontally

**i also, find a WARNING as Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.**

i tried adding the following code...there is no change

```
document.addEventListener( "touchstart", function(e){ onStart(e); }, false );
    function onStart ( touchEvent ) {
      if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ) {
       touchEvent.preventDefault();
      }
    }
```

**Any remedy or solution for this??**

Comment: Any luck ? Were you able to solve this ?

Comment: 2-Stroker,i could partially solve the problem by switching to this option [check this](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper) **BUT I FACED and STILL FACING 2 PROBLEMS** 1 is while swiping if i have given margin-left to the slide...as and when i swipe the space gets added up and only half of the slide is to be seen on your 4th swipe.....2nd problem it is not dynamic..something like based on the length of your data...you need to set the values....**otherwise WORKS FINE**

Comment: this code structure in the question is the exact answer for this question. Please [refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542178/can-we-use-a-variable-to-declare-a-div-in-javascript),for the answer.